# Can't install lib32ncurses5-dev or ia32-libs

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install Android source and I keep getting this error. I kept with the installation but seems these packages are sort of required to have a complete and successful installation.

this is my error

```
Package lib32ncurses5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lib32ncurses5-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lib32readline5-dev
E: Unable to locate package lib32z-dev
```

I have a VM with Ubuntu on  Intel® Core™ i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz 
and 32-bit system

Comment: Can you add a link to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Just drop it on pastebin.ubuntu.com and link it here, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`ia32-libs` is in the `universe` [component](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). It sounds like you don't have this repository enabled.

You need to enable it, either in Software Center -> [Software Sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab), or by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncommenting lines with `universe` at the end.

Don't forget to do an `apt-get update` (or press Update in Update Manager)

Comment: did that but did not help

Answer (score 2):

This problem existed on Ubuntu 11.10.

I solved the issue by opening a terminal and used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev:i386
```

Comment: the same problem exists

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 I needed to execute below command,

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev:i386
```